# Validating non-model field in Rails 4.2

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that includes an input field that does not correspond with a model attribute:

```
<%= f.text_field :non-model-field %>
```

I have used `attr_accessor` to validate the input in my model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :non-model-field
  validates :non-model-field, presence: true
end
```

What is the recommended way of doing this type of validation in Rails 4.2?

Comment: Just like that, you are correct!